# How to hide Bootstrap modal when browser back/forward button is clicked in Ember JS

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ember.js, modal-dialog

I have an Ember application with a modal dialog code from this article: http://ember.guru/2014/master-your-modals-in-ember-js

What is the best way to close/hide it, when back or forward button is clicked in the browser.

At the moment, the overlay and the modal dialog will remain visible while to content behind them will change to previous/next page.

Here's a JSBin:
http://emberjs.jsbin.com/rifesaroqe

**application.hbs:**

```
{{outlet}}
{{outlet 'modal'}}
```

**routes/application.js:**

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  actions: {
    showModal: function(name, model) {
      this.render(name, {
        into: 'application',
        outlet: 'modal',
        model: model
      });
    },
    removeModal: function() {
      this.disconnectOutlet({
        outlet: 'modal',
        parentView: 'application'
      });
    }
  }
});
```

**components/my-modal.js:**

```
App.MyModalComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  actions: {
    ok: function() {
      this.$('.modal').modal('hide');
      this.sendAction('ok');
    }
  },
  show: function() {
    this.$('.modal').modal().on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
      this.sendAction('close');
    }.bind(this));
  }.on('didInsertElement')
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated JSBin - http://emberjs.jsbin.com/hiqame/2

For your particular example, the best way is to use the `didTransition` event on the Route [(link to docs)](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#event_didTransition). In Ember, whenever an active route transitions successfully into another route, that active route fires the `didTransition` action. You can then use the `send` method ([link to docs](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_send)) from the route to trigger the `removeModal` action, which will close the modal.

Comment: Thank you. This is so simple but I'm not sure if I understand how it works. Does `didTransition` action in the `ApplicationRoute` fire on every single transition anywhere in the application? I thought the `ApplicationRoute` is only called on initial request.

Comment: Yeah, it does fire on every single transition. You can see that in action [here](http://jsbin.com/hiqame/3/edit?js,console,output).